# HTTP status code: 404 Received error: Code: 47, e.displayText() = DB::Exception: Unknown identifier: TableauSQL.cnt, e.what() = DB::Exception

Tags: odbc, tableau-api, clickhouse

I connected to clickhouse with tableau.

A query like this

```
select * from table_name limit 1
```

returns fields of the table, even though it should return raws.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4f7bW.png)

If I try

```
select subs_key from table name limit 1
```

And click **preview results**

[preview results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6ghr.png)

I get the error from above(except `cnt` is replaced with `subs_key` or whatever field I try to select)

How can I actually view table data?

Edit

There is a connection to the db, but no table is shown in available schemas.

EDIT 2

I managed to connect and get data from an oracle and mysql database, but while I am connected to click house, I can't see any data.

Answer (score 0):

Don't quote me on this but I believe tableau has not official support for clickhouse, at least I could not find anything to contradict this, tons of people asking for it but nothing concrete.

There might some sort of beta integration that's not yet stable, hence you problem, but this is just blind guessing.

What I can recommend, if you really need a UI and can't just use the cl client is using tabix:

https://github.com/smi2/tabix.ui

Its fully open source for now and should be pretty easy and straight forward to learn, there might be the odd bits of Russian here and there, but I believe its getting debugged and translated at quite a good pace.

Comment: I contacted a developer from tableau. Turns out that it aliases(is that a word?) every table and field. That's why I got the mistake. Unfortunately it seems like turning this function off is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

I get the same error message when I use DBeaver.

```
SQL Error [47]: ClickHouse exception, Code: 47, e.displayText() = 
DB::Exception: Unknown identifier: default_type, e.what() = DB::Exception
```

If it's not a coincidence, then it's a JDBC driver bug.